# How to display LinkedIn sign in button

Tags: javascript, html, api, linkedin-api

Hi I'm trying to get the LinkedIn api working at a basic level. Where I make an HTML page that shows the LinkedIn sign in button. I followed the steps on the LinkedIn developer page and copied the code directly. I'm wondering if I have an issue with the OAuth2.0?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>LinkedIn Api</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Linked In java script Api initialize -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key:  myKey
    onLoad:    onLinkedInLoad
    authorize: true
</script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">

    // Setup an event listener to make an API call once auth is complete
    function onLinkedInLoad() {
        IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);
    }

    // Handle the successful return from the API call
    function onSuccess(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }

    // Handle an error response from the API call
    function onError(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    // Use the API call wrapper to request the member's basic profile data
    function getProfileData() {
        IN.API.Raw("/people/~").result(onSuccess).error(onError);
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 <script type="in/Login" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js"></script>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?  You haven't really said anything about what's not working.

Comment: @JustinKominar honestly nothing shows up at when i open up the link, I feel the error is with my OAuth2.0 login